# Calculating power from torque

Tags: torque, power

so for my project im designing a Tesla turbine and have calculated that the torque it will output is 38Nm. I would like to know what more information I would need that i could calculate theoretically to calculate how much power it would output from this.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a *really basic* physics question.

Comment: Power = torque * rotational speed. If using SI units, that's Nm * radians/second, giving watts.

Answer (score 1):

general power formula is 2*3.14159 * N *T

you need to know revolutions per second for finding power.
there are various tachometers available. (stroboscope,aluminum cup,mechanical tachometer, etc) get the reading of revolution per min. convert it to rev per sec.

then use it in the formula p = 2*3.1415*N*(38)

Comment: there is even a mobile app that can estimate revolutions per minute

Comment: The 2*Pi is only an artefact of not using SI units properly.

Comment: gee, if you convert rpm to rad/s shouldnt there be a 60 in there someplace?

Comment: If you are using rad/sec, then you don't need to divide by 60. Power is in joule per second

Answer (score 0):

Power is force times speed.

If your shaft is turning at 1 Hz, for example, then the power is

(38 N)(2Π m/s) = 239 Nm/s = 239 W